# Angular 2 and Material Designs - example dialog is empty

Tags: angular, dialog, modal-dialog, material-design

I'm trying to create a Dialog Box as shown in the Material Designs page [Here](https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog). I can get the button to show up, click on it, the dialog box shows up and the page darkens as expected but no text shows up. I feel like I'm close but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Here is my code:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) { }

  openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}


@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console? You're also missing the `dialogRef` dependency in your `DialogOverviewComponent` as you have no constructor.

Comment: Yes. It says that  Cannot find name 'DialogOverviewExampleDialog'.) and No component factory found for DialogOverviewExampleDialog. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents? even though it is there. Could you explain what you mean by dialogRef? It is mentioned later on in the documentation but it is not in the example code.

Comment: And if I try DialogOverviewExampleDialogComponent that gives an error too, "No component factory found for DialogOverviewExampleDialog. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you may be missing a few things in your attempt.

First in your code, be sure to include the `MdDialogRef` in your `DialogOverviewExampleDialog` class constructor, like so, per the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog):

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef} from '@angular/material'; // Added "MdDialogRef"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {}

  openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog);

    // If you need a result from your dialog
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      // Do something with result, if needed.
    });
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  // Added Constructor
  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>) {}
}
```

Secondly, for the error:

> No component factory found for DialogOverviewExampleDialog. Did you
>   add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Your `app.module.ts` must define your dialog component (`DialogOverviewExampleDialog`) in ***two places***: `declarations` *and* `entryComponents`.

For example:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    DialogOverviewExampleDialog // HERE
  ],
  entryComponents: [ 
    DialogOverviewExampleDialog // AND HERE
  ],
  ...
```

Comment: Same basically goes for the now renamed MatDialog - if it's empty you most likely missed the `entryComponents` entry.

Comment: In case anyone else suffered from the same problem, you will have empty content if you set the `selector` to `dialog`. Name it _anything else_: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8601

Comment: @asgaines great that I saw your comment!